# Arctan inequality: $\arctan(|y-x|)\le\arctan(x)+\arctan(y)$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

i'm trying make a geometrical demonstration of inequality  for $\arctan$

$$\arctan(|y-x|)\le\arctan(x)+\arctan(y)$$

[image: arctan inequal]

only work for $x>0$ and $y>0$

so i split in two case.

if $y>x$

$a=\arctan(y)$ , $b=\arctan(x)$ 
and $c=\arctan(y-x)$

so for angle, $a\geqslant c$ and how $b>0$ 
to
$c\leqslant a\leqslant a+b$ so $c\leqslant a+b$ 
and 
$\arctan(y-x)\le\arctan(x)+\arctan(y)$

what do you think? is good

Answer (score 1):

> so i split in two case.
>
> if $y > x$

The problem is symmetric in $\,x,y\,$ since $\,|y-x|=|x-y|\,$, so you can assume WLOG that $\,y \ge x\,$. There is no need to `split in two cases`.

> so for angle, $a>=c$

That *does* in fact hold true, but it may not be immediately obvious. In my opinion, it would work better if the figure showed *why* $\,a \ge c\,$ more clearly.

[image]

Other than that, good question and well asked (+1).

Answer (score 0):

If a and b are non-negative numbers then $arctan (a+b)+arctan (a)-arctan (b)$ is an increasing function of $a$. This function vanishes when a=0 so it is non-negative everywhere. Put a=y,b=x-y to see that $arctan x +arctan y-arctan (x-y) \geq 0$ provided $x \geq y$. This is the required inequality for this case; for $x<y$ simply interchange x and y.